# How to open a new page when I click on each item of a list?

Tags: android, android-listview, static

I am new in Android. I have a static list view and I want to click on each Item and go to the detail page . this is the code for making static list now on item click shows a toast but I want it goes to another page.can you please help how should I change it? and how can I implement the array adopter for it ?

```
public class Agenda extends ListActivity {


    static final String[] Agenda = new String[] { "Iphone", "Samsung",
            "Galaxy s4", "Nexus"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_mobile,
        //      R.id.label, MOBILE_OS));

        setListAdapter(new AgendaArrayAdapter(this, Agenda));


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Details_List.class);
    i.putExtra("device_name", selectedValue);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And In **Detail_List Class:**

```
public class Detail_List extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details);

    String selected_Device = getIntent().getStringExtra("device_name");

    // do whatever on this behalf of selected_Device String
}

}
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped u

Comment: Another question is that I want to implement View.OnClickListener in the detail class to show the menu items in the action bar but the app crashes can you please tell me what is the problem why it crashes?

Comment: Its a seperate question :) post it on SO

Answer (score 0):

You should try to start a new activity when you click an item, like this:
Add `setOnItemclickListener()` for your Listview.

```
ListView listView = getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setOnItemClickListener (listener);

OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener (){

  @Override
  onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
      String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtText)).getText();
      Intent intent = new Intent(context,WhatEverYouWant.class);
      intent.putExtra("name",name);
      startActivity(intent);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your main:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
  int position, long id) {
switch(position)
{
   case 0:  
Intent newActivity = new Intent(Agenda.this, Samsung.class);     
startActivity(newActivity);
break;
   case 1: 
Intent i= new Intent(Agenda.this, GalaxyS4.class);     
startActivity(i);
break;
   case 2:  
Intent i1= new Intent(Agenda.this, iPhone.class);     
startActivity(i1); //iPhone , change it by your created class for iPhone
break;

   case 3: 
Intent i3= new Intent(Agenda.this, Nexus4.class);     
startActivity(i3);
break;
}
```